# Делится ли число целочисленно на 10?

Tags: java

Простое число `int`.
Нужно определить делится ли оно на 10 целочисленно. 
Все вроде просто, но ничего в голову не идет. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам во всех ответах совершенно правильно посоветовали использовать операцию `%` для получения остатка от деления. А вот если бы ее не было, то можно было бы поступить так -- `if ((a / 10) * 10 == a) // да, чисто делится на 10`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Используй для подобного рода задач оператор `%`, возвращающий остаток от деления **левого значения** на **правое**.

Пример:

```
number = 10;
if(number%10==0) System.out.println("Число делится на 10");
```

Answer (score 10):

Для этого есть оператор "%", результатом работы которого является остаток от деления.

С помощью него такая задача решается достаточно тривиально:

```
int a=15;
if(a%10==0) //В нашем случае результатом будет 5, значит проверка не пройдет
{
 //Делится на 10 целочисленно
 ...
}
else
{
 //Не делится
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Вам нужно использовать остаток от деления, а это значит что нужно

```
int number = 10;

if (number % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.pritln(number);
}
```

То есть, учите матчать )

Answer (score 8):

Вот простая функция для проверки. Если делится - возвращает true, иначе - false.

```
public boolean byTen(int n){
      return n % 10 == 0;
}
```